# Program declaring variables by itself

Tags: c++, variables, variable-declaration

I am still a ... novice, in c++.
I don't know the name of what I am looking for but
I 've been searching a lot but can't seem to find the answer to following question:
I want to write a program that would declare demanded number of variables.
Example:

```
int a;
cin>>a;
```

Now if "a" is 5 (or any other number), I want program to declare 5 more variables,
Names do not matter but let's say...n1,n2,n3,n4,n5.
I've tried array and for loop but can't get it to work.
I got answer on Croatian forum (forum.hr) but the forum is currently offline, so I had no
time to try it out...
It was about using heap instead of stack
Thx in advance

Comment: Is that number defined by the user or is it constant?

Answer (score 2):

[C++ has container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) for this purpose. In particular, you want a `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> a(size);
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    std::cin >> a[i];
```

Declares a vector `a` of integers of some size and reads its elements, one by one.

Comment: Vectors are new to me...
Can vector's elements be used as variables?
I want to do some matemathical operations on the values in further code.
Can I do that by using vectors?

Answer (score 1):

you can store them in an array:

```
int a;
cin >> a;

int *number = new int[a];  // allocate an array of size a

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    number[i] = 5 + i;     // set your numbers to anything here
}

delete[] number;             // otherwise you have memory leak
```

or better use a `vector`:

```
vector<int> number(a);

// iterate with a normal for loop
for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
    number[i] = 5 + i;
}

..

// or use iterators
for (vector<int>::iterator it = number.begin(); it != number.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

so you don't have to manage memory.

Comment: -1 this is such bad C++ code it makes my heart bleed. Please don’t ever again use `malloc` in C++. Don’t use manual memory management in this situation at all.

Comment: The first one is non-standard C++ extension in GCC and won't work in other compilers. For the other two you need to release the memory, and in the case of `malloc` you should not use `sizeof(int)`, but rather `sizeof *number` (as that removes the repetition of the type)

Comment: removed `malloc` and stack allocations. `new` or `vector` seem to be the most appropriate..

Comment: Ok, I used arrays and for loops but I 've never heard of vectors until now.
I did googling so I know they are kindda like arrays but more editable and stuff.
So I can use values stored in them like independet variables?
If inputed number is 5, I want 5 variables that I can use further in code. Now since I am a noob, can You pls clarify the code so I get the logic... It's still kindda... confuseing

Comment: @Kula If you know how many variables you will have beforehand and it's not increasing or decreasing during the program, you may just use regular arrays. In order to understand the internals of a vector and why they are useful, you should probably have an algorithms class or equivalently do some readings like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29) or [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Answer (score 1):

If this is C++, the best you can do is using `std::vector` as it will manage the memory for you.